# Syntax error before '->' for no apparent reason

Tags: syntax, erlang, syntax-error

I am defining some functions in an Erlang script file and calling them in main to demonstrate their correctness. I have not had any problems up to now, but suddenly I'm getting an error for no real reason. Here is the code in question (I have checked that this line is the problem by commenting it out):

```
fibSeq() -> [0] ++ [1] ++ lists:zipwith(func(X, Y) -> X + Y end, fibs(), lists:delete(0, fibSeq())).
```

The idea behind this function is to efficiently calculate the Fibonacci sequence. It's possible the error is arising because of the infinite recursive nature of the function, however I believe I read that Erlang uses lazy evaluation, so I feel like this should work.

Edit: The usage of this would be `list:sublist(fibSeq(), N)` or `list:nth(N, fibSeq())` where `N` is an integer.

Edit 2:
The error message is `"Syntax error before '->'"` with reference to the line number one above the fibSeq() function, and the code before it is

```
merge([], []) -> [];
merge(A, []) -> A;
merge([], B) -> B;
merge([A|As], [B|Bs]) when A < B -> [A] ++ merge(As, [B] ++ Bs);
merge([A|As], [B|Bs]) -> [B] ++ merge([A] ++ As, Bs).

mergesort([]) -> [];
mergesort([A]) -> [A];
mergesort(As) ->
    merge(mergesort(lists:sublist(As, length(As) div 2)), mergesort(lists:sublist(As, length(As) div 2 + 1, length(As) div 2 + 1))).
```

I have changed my fibonacci code to use a different linear evaluation that I thought of shortly after:

```
fib(N) when N >= 0, is_integer(N) ->  fibHelp(0, 1, N).

fibHelp(L, _, 0) -> L;
fibHelp(L, H, A) when A > 0, is_integer(L), is_integer(H), is_integer(A) ->
    fibHelp(H, L+H, A - 1).
```

Comment: 1. What is the error message? 2. What does the previous line look like? 3. Erlang does _not_ use lazy evaluation, so the function will loop infinitely, but this is not a syntax error.

Comment: I'll add edits per your request, as well as an updated version of what I am doing. Regardless of the syntax error, the fact that Erlang does not use lazy evaluation means this won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for higher order functions in erlang is `fun(X) -> X * 2 end`. Using `func` is a syntax error.